# Two sided projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, terminology

Is there a special name for the linear operator $P:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that projects on the subspace $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$ when acting from left, i.e., $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Px\in A$, and projects on $B\in\mathbb{R}^n$ when acting from right, i.e., $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $yP\in B$?

Comment: Do you mean "projects", or that the images on the left and right are subspaces of $A$ and $B$? In particular, do you mean that for $a \in A$, you have $Pa  = a$? That's required for a "projection". And do you mean that $A$ is contained in the image of $P$, or equal to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear operator $P$ on a space $V$ is a projector if it satisfies $P^2=P$. When that is the case, the image of$~P$ (acting from the left on vectors) is a subspace $A\subseteq V$ with (by definition) $P\cdot v\in A$ for all $v\in V$, and moreover $P|_A=\mathrm{id}_A$. Dually there is an image subspace $B\subseteq V^*$ for $P$ acting on the right on the dual space $V^*$, with (again by definition) $\phi\cdot P\in B$ for all linear forms $\phi\in V^*$, and $P$ acts on the right as the identity on$~B$. It is not hard to see that $B$ is the set of linear forms vanishing on $\ker P\subseteq V$.

In other words, *all* projectors are of the kind you describe, for appropriate $A$ and $B$.